# Show that there only two solutions to $p \mid (k^2 - 1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I apologize if the question's silly, but I cannot prove that $p \mid (k^2 - 1)$ implies $k \in \{ 1, p - 1 \}$ for some prime $p$ ($k \in \{1, 2, ...  , p - 1 \}$ is a given).

$p|(k^2 - 1) \implies k^2 \equiv 1 \pmod p \implies k^2 = mp + 1$

I only know from a different problem that if $p \mid (xk - 1)$ then $x \in \{1, 2, ...  , p - 1 \}$, but I don't know how to continue and show that $1$ and $p - 1$ are the only possible solutions.

I'm probably missing something very obvious?
Help would be very appreciated.

Comment: What are the conditions on $k$? As $p=3$ and $k=5$ also works.

Comment: Actually, $p\mid k^2-1$ implies $(k\bmod p)\in\{1,p-1\}$.

Comment: The claim "$p\mid k^2-1$ implies $k\in\{1,p-1\}$" is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that $k \in \{1, 2, ...  , p - 1 \}$ is a given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(k^2 -1) = (k + 1)(k - 1)$.

So either $p \mid (k + 1)$, in which case $k \equiv -1 \pmod p \equiv p - 1 \pmod p$.
Or $p \mid (k - 1)$, in which case $k \equiv 1 \pmod p$.

Comment: I can't believe it... I was so obsessed with properties of modular arithmetic, that I completely overlooked such a simple factorization... Thanks, I was seriously scratching my head for half an hour.

Comment: the prime $p$ has to be greater than $2$.

Comment: @Ben Why can't $p$ be $2$?  Then it's still true that $k \in \{1,p-1\}$, it's just that the latter set has only one element.

Comment: It is just sth minor. I mean both cases can happen at the same time. In this situation, it turns out that both cases actually are the same.

Comment: @Ashura $p\mid (k+1)(k-1)\implies \left(p\mid k+1\text{ or }p\mid k-1\right)$ follows from [Euclid's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma).

Answer (score 0):

$p|(k^2-1) \Rightarrow p|(k-1)(k+1)$

either $p|(k-1)$ or $p|(k+1)$

if $p|(k-1)$ then $p \le k-1 \Rightarrow k \ge p+1$

if $p|(k+1)$ then $p \le k+1 \Rightarrow k \ge p-1$

since $k \in \{1,2,3,...p-1\}$

$k\{1,p-1\}$

Answer (score 0):

$p$ divides $(k+1)(k-1)$ implies $p$ divides $k+1$ or $p$ divides $k-1$.

Comment: Just a little more explanation, to connect with the OP's desired conclusion that $k\equiv \pm 1 \bmod{p}$, would probably improve this answer.